# OctoberCMS - Rainlab User Plugin - onLogout - Not found

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-user-plugin

**Login page**

Included User's Account component in login.htm page, `data-request="onSignin"` works fine
[image]

**Logout button**

Included Session's component in the navigation partial, `data-request="onLogout"` , hit error
[image]

**Ajax handler not found**
[image]

Questions: Can I include [session] in global partial to make sure "Logout" Ajax handler can trigger on every pages?

OR do I need to include [session] in each of every my created pages *( this seems really hardcoded )* ? May I know what's the best practice of doing/including the component

```
[session]
security = "all"
==
<header>    
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="{{ 'login'|page }}">Login</a></li>
            <li><a data-request="onLogout" data-request-data="redirect: '/good-bye'">Sign out</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **Session** component globally if you will add a session in your default layout file e.g. `default.htm`

So Open you default layout in Backend **CMS** menu and assign **session** component there and `onLogout` error will be solved for sure.

If any doubt please comment.

Comment: Hello, i did add session component in default.htm , its still the same, the ajax error still popping out.

Comment: And are you sure that you are using menu/header file under the same layout? Because this is the best practice to use session globally.

Comment: Please remove session file from navigation partial and add session to default layout and don't forget to save it.

Comment: Thanks! It's working, seems like I have multiple session in some of the pages/partials, I've standardise and put the session & account component in layout files.

Comment: Yeah! That's great.